# query to pull one row per id when multiple rows of each id exist in table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table holding email addresses where some people have more than one email address listed.  I want to query the table to only pull a single email address per Individual.

Columns are:

ID

IndividualID

Email

Example data:

1  34   dave@gmail.com

2  65   bob@gmail.com

3  34   david@gmail.com

What I want as the result set is (Only pull one row per IndividualID):

1  34   dave@gmail.com

2  65   bob@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (
    ID int,
    IndividualID int,
    Email varchar(128)
)

INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES 
(1, 34, 'dave@gmail.com'),
(2, 65, 'bob@gmail.com'),
(3, 34, 'david@gmail.com')

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IndividualId ORDER BY ID)
    FROM @sample
) AS data
WHERE RN = 1
```